# Shortcut key to modify stored procedure in ssms

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, keyboard-shortcuts

In SQL Server Management Studio,
Object Explorer Details where Stored Procedure Listing shows, 
I want here to press a shortcut key on any stored procedure to open its modify window.

Answer (score 10):

I can't find anything in the documentation about this.

The quickest I've found is <kbd>Right Click</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd> (when you've got a stored procedure highlighted in Object explorer).

Edit: If you do need an entirely keyboard based version, you can simulate the right click with <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>.

[Source](http://chriscatto.blogspot.co.uk/2009/08/sql-server-management-studio-hotkeys.html)

Comment: Did not know about shift+F10 for right-click. That solves one of the most frustrating things about my new laptop keyboard, a lack of right-click key... thank you  :-)

Comment: BTW, you can format "keyboard" style using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> - I would edit your post, but it would then have to be peer-reviewed

Comment: @Bridge - I am sorry dear; i did't want this;

Comment: @ghazanfarseyal What did you want? I've answered the original question.