# how to view the stored procedure by keyword command in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

example  alt+f1 we do for the table property to see

Like that there is command for this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shortcut key to modify stored procedure in ssms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10847934/shortcut-key-to-modify-stored-procedure-in-ssms)

Answer (score 2):

Add `exec sp_helptext <Stored Procedure Name>` to you Query Shortcuts.

On the management studio, Tools->Options->Environment->Keyboad->Query Shortcuts.

And exit and open management studio.  Then use the short cut which you added.

Comment: exec sp_helptext <Stored Procedure Name> do i need to put  my sp name here but i want to use as many as possible to exec

Comment: yes, you need to add your stored procedure. ed: exec sp_helptext dbo.spr_test.  If you want to see the properties for multiple procedures, then give the command semicolon separated in the same shortcut as exec sp_helptext spr_test1;exec sp_helptext spr_test2;

Comment: like this i have to for all the stored procedure but i need for multiple procedure can you tell me in that manner

Comment: Create a stored procedure for exec sp_helptext of your all stored procedure and use ctrl+<key> for this stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add short cut key in the sql option under tool section